# tinybutstrong alternative for Java

Tags: java, report, template-engine, tinybutstrong, xdocreport

Is there are Template Engine for Java that can build docx/odt reports from docx/odt templates? I've already tried *xdocreport* but there are only row- and cell-based blocks but I need whole-table-block. Is there are something for Java like *tinybutstrong* for PHP?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean with whole-table-block? If you wish loop for table-cols with XDocReport it's possible with [advanced table](http://code.google.com/p/xdocreport/wiki/DocxReportingJavaMainListFieldAdvancedTable) by using @before-cell and @after-cell. See [DocxTableWithoutFieldsMetadataWithVelocity](http://code.google.com/p/xdocreport/source/browse/samples/fr.opensagres.xdocreport.samples.docxandvelocity/src/fr/opensagres/xdocreport/samples/docxandvelocity/?repo=samples) sample (java and docx).

The docx contains that :

---

«@before-row#foreach($d in $developers)»«$d.Name»

«@after-row#end»

«@before-cell#foreach($r in $d.Roles)»«$r.Name»«@after-cell#end»

---

which loops for each developpers (to generate row) and for each row it loops for each cells (dynamic columns) to generate a row per role of developers.

This syntax is a little complex, but you can manage dynamic columns.